# Windows 7 Enterprise under virtualization has no networking until login

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, linux-kvm

I created a Windows 7 image to run under KVM based virtualiztion, but the networking for the image will not start until I login. I'm not very familiar with Windows, but it seems as though there is some kind of policy being applied for "unknown" networks and connecting to the internet until a user logs in.

Does anyone have any ideas of where to start looking to troublshoot this problem? It's a bit hard to good because of the search terms. It always ends up being about network logins.

Thanks for any help.